# What is the compilation error in this code... I tried my best but I could not resolve the error

Tags: sql, ordbms

I want to add this member function to the type I created. I already altered the type.
I want to know what is the compilation error in this code and I want to know the solution for this?
This code is related to ORDB(Object Relational Database).

I have tried this changing the variables and I looked at syntaxes also.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Project_typ AS 
MEMBER FUNCTION count_emp RETURN INTEGER
IS
MCOUNT INTEGER;
MANAGERcount INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(SELF.mgr) INTO MANAGERcount
    FROM Projects_tbl;
        IF(MANAGERcount > 0){
            SELECT COUNT(M.team_member) INTO MCOUNT
            FROM Projects_tbl, TABLE(SELF.members) M
            GROUP BY SELF.pname;
        }
        ELSE{
            MCOUNT = -1;
        }
        END IF;
    RETURN MCOUNT;
END count_emp;
END;
```

I am expecting to return a integer value.
If a manager is there, return the number of members working on that project.
If a manager is not there, return -1.

Comment: Can you post you log errors?

Comment: Why do you tag it with this `C#` tags?

Comment: Yeah this is not C#